# A regular expression to exclude a specific string '[[' via sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, regex-negation

I need to fetch string which between '[[' and ']]' using sed in file: response.txt

```
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-server-response-time: 63
x-dropbox-request-id: 84e52618f83eda15cb6d96eb4f601f45
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
x-dropbox-http-protocol: None
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN

{"has_more": false, "cursor": "AAEynx2q5KMgkcOwL2dKZ4MCYxNTtsdA950A5kYOdjWFln_RYuAokMnJCOb85B7idOHjycS8LJye3BhWfezTkkoprVxhgMNni_Bg04A-JO9fLmqIGO3CYInBQPmNUXL57S32ECWwA-CYu1CiLi5ujTDz", "entries": [["/test", {"rev": "b1e9026cf6f4", "thumb_exists": false, "path": "/TEST", "is_dir": true, "icon": "folder", "read_only": false, "modifier": null, "bytes": 0, "modified": "Fri, 22 May 2015 05:53:27 +0000", "size": "0 bytes", "root": "dropbox", "revision": 45545}], ["/TEST/test-file-01", {"rev": "b1ed026cf6f4", "thumb_exists": false, "path": "/test/test-file-01", "is_dir": true, "icon": "folder", "read_only": false, "modifier": null, "bytes": 0, "modified": "Fri, 22 May 2015 06:15:33 +0000", "size": "0 bytes", "root": "dropbox", "revision": 45549}]], "reset": true}
```

And want to using command `sed` to fetch the string, result is as below:

```
[["/test", {"rev": "b1e9026cf6f4", "thumb_exists": false, "path": "/TEST", "is_dir": true, "icon": "folder", "read_only": false, "modifier": null, "bytes": 0, "modified": "Fri, 22 May 2015 05:53:27 +0000", "size": "0 bytes", "root": "dropbox", "revision": 45545}], ["/TEST/test-file-01", {"rev": "b1ed026cf6f4", "thumb_exists": false, "path": "/test/test-file-01", "is_dir": true, "icon": "folder", "read_only": false, "modifier": null, "bytes": 0, "modified": "Fri, 22 May 2015 06:15:33 +0000", "size": "0 bytes", "root": "dropbox", "revision": 45549}]]
```

I run the command in terminal:

`$ sed -n 's/.*"entries": *\(\[\[.*\]\]\)/\1/p' /tmp/response.txt`

And get the result:

```
[["/test", {"rev": "b1e9026cf6f4", "thumb_exists": false, "path": "/TEST", "is_dir": true, "icon": "folder", "read_only": false, "modifier": null, "bytes": 0, "modified": "Fri, 22 May 2015 05:53:27 +0000", "size": "0 bytes", "root": "dropbox", "revision": 45545}], ["/TEST/test-file-01", {"rev": "b1ed026cf6f4", "thumb_exists": false, "path": "/test/test-file-01", "is_dir": true, "icon": "folder", "read_only": false, "modifier": null, "bytes": 0, "modified": "Fri, 22 May 2015 06:15:33 +0000", "size": "0 bytes", "root": "dropbox", "revision": 45549}]], "reset": true}
```

Then, I run the command in terminal:

`$ sed -n 's/.*"entries": *\(\[\[(?!\]\].)*\]\]\)/\1/p' /tmp/response.txt`

And return nothing.

Seems I write wrong regex? How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot see a difference between the two commands you typed in your terminal. Are you explaining that running it twice does not produce the same result?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Sorry, I updated the second command!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed recognizes Posix regexes, which do not include lookaround assertions like `(?!`.

Fortunately, it's easy to write a regex for this simple case (as usual, it's less easy to read):

```
sed -n 's/.*"entries": *\(\[\[\(]\?[^]]\)*]]\)/\1/p' /tmp/response.txt
```

However, it wasn't greedy matching that caused the problem with your initial attempt. The problem was that you aren't discarding the contents of the line which follows the match. What you wanted was:

```
sed -n 's/.*"entries": *\(\[\[\(]\?[^]]\)*]]\).*/\1/p' /tmp/response.txt
```

The fact that `sed` uses "Basic" Posix regexes (BREs) means that you end up with a lot of backslashes. I've tried to remove at least some of them, using the fact that `]` is *not* special in a regex except when it is closing a character class. But on the whole, I think your needs would be better satisfied using `grep`, which has a Posix-standard option to use "Extended" (normal) regexes (EREs), and an option to only print out the matching string:

```
grep -oE '"entries": \[\[(]?[^]])*]]' /tmp/response.txt | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

(The `cut` at the end is to remove `"entries":` )

#### Explanation of the regex

The regex (in the ERE form) consists of:

```
\[\[           match [[
(
  ]?             possibly a single ]
  [^]]           anything but a ]
)*               repeated as many times as necessary
]]            match ]]
```

The repeated group will match either `]` followed by anthing but a `]`, or it will match anything but a `]`. In effect, it is (almost) the negation of `]]`.

(It's not quite the negation because it won't match a single `]` at the end of the string, but that doesn't matter here because we're insisting that it be followed by the closing `]]`, so the case where it reaches the end of the string doesn't occur.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Important to me:  ] is not special in a regex except when it is closing a character class. I learned from you :)

Answer (score 2):

Avoid parsing JSON with regular expressions. Use a proper parser.

If you have `jq`installed:

```
awk -v RS="" "END {print}" response.txt | jq -c '.["entries"]'
```

```
[["/test",{"revision":45545,"root":"dropbox","size":"0 bytes","modified":"Fri, 22 May 2015 05:53:27 +0000","rev":"b1e9026cf6f4","thumb_exists":false,"path":"/TEST","is_dir":true,"icon":"folder","read_only":false,"modifier":null,"bytes":0}],["/TEST/test-file-01",{"revision":45549,"root":"dropbox","size":"0 bytes","modified":"Fri, 22 May 2015 06:15:33 +0000","rev":"b1ed026cf6f4","thumb_exists":false,"path":"/test/test-file-01","is_dir":true,"icon":"folder","read_only":false,"modifier":null,"bytes":0}]]
```

Or ruby:

```
ruby -rjson -e '
    data = (File.readlines(ARGV.shift))[-1]
    json = JSON.parse(data)
    puts JSON.generate(json["entries"])
' response.txt
```

```
[["/test",{"rev":"b1e9026cf6f4","thumb_exists":false,"path":"/TEST","is_dir":true,"icon":"folder","read_only":false,"modifier":null,"bytes":0,"modified":"Fri, 22 May 2015 05:53:27 +0000","size":"0 bytes","root":"dropbox","revision":45545}],["/TEST/test-file-01",{"rev":"b1ed026cf6f4","thumb_exists":false,"path":"/test/test-file-01","is_dir":true,"icon":"folder","read_only":false,"modifier":null,"bytes":0,"modified":"Fri, 22 May 2015 06:15:33 +0000","size":"0 bytes","root":"dropbox","revision":45549}]]
```

or any language of your choice that implements a JSON parser.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I need using shell script to store the string(json) as variable, so wanna fetch the string using kind of sed command.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\n/!{s/\[\[/\n&/g;s/\]\]/&\n/g};/^\[\[/P;D' file
```

If the pattern space does not contain a `\n` then prepend a `\n` to all `[[` strings and append a `\n` to all `]]` strings. If the pattern space begins with `[[` then print upto the following `\n` (or end of the pattern space). Delete upto the next `\n` (or end of the pattern space) and repeat until the pattern space is empty.

N.B. this will only print strings between newlines that begin and end with the required string (`[[`or`]]`).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed -n 's/.*"entries": *\(\[\[.*\]\]\).*/\1/p'
```

instead (note the `.*` at the end of the pattern).